# HTML/CSS: How do I make right floats go to the top instead of floating at the position where they were when they were inline?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, on this page you see 3 images that are `float:right` inside the `.container` that has a red border:
http://cis.scc.losrios.edu/~cisw320b_stu022/sccwa-snapshot1/

The images start halfway down because that is where they were initially placed with respect to the content on the left.

How can I make them go all the way to the top without (with CSS preferably)?

**EDIT 11/8/2011 4:06pm:** Try resizing your browser to make it smaller and smaller and you'll see that the images get placed inline. That is because as the size of the browser shrinks, the float:right property is removed so that the images go inline into the same spot as they are in the code. I can't simply put the `<aside>` elements before all the `<p>` elements because then when you shrink your browser the images will no longer be in the correct positions.

**EDIT 11/8/2011 4:11pm:** So basically I want it so when the window is smaller, all the asides appear in their correct inline positions, but when the browser window is bigger, all the images should appear on the right side as if they were in a sidebar on the right.

Is this possible with CSS?

**EDIT 11/8/2011 4:16pm:** The website is supposed to shrink on purpose. Try resizing your browser so it is the width of an iPhone or an Android. The `<aside>` elements appear inline where they should. But when the browser is full size on a desktop, I want the `<aside>` elements to float on the right, starting from the top.

Is this possible with CSS, or do I have to use Javascript?

Comment: Just a thought - float is performing exactly as it should - it's staying in the correct vertical position, and staying to the side of the text. What you're asking for sounds a lot like something that would require DOM re-ordering. I dunno, I may just not be enough of a CSS magician to do this, but it would definitely be feasible in Javascript.

Comment: For sure, yeah that's what I think too. A CSS feature for that would be nice!

Comment: What's the point of using aside element (and 3 of them, quite unusual) if you want to move it visually very far from the content it follows (but only if screen is wide)? Are they related to the surrounding paragraphs and then don't move them visually far from them or aran't they and then Charlie and Shomz's answers are perfectly valid?

Comment: FOr example, those could be inline advertisements, or other content suited for the sidebar when in full desktop mode.

Comment: It might not practical in all cases, but I was just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that what I want is not possible without Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Put the aside elements before all the p elements in the main div.

Instead of:

```
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<aside>...</aside>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<aside>...</aside>
<p>...</p>
```

Use:

```
<aside>...</aside>
<aside>...</aside>
<aside>...</aside>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
...
```

UPDATE: 
Make a new CSS rule/stylesheet for the phones only: #main aside {float: none;}.
See [this](http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/mobile-css.htm) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Shomz, but try resizing your browser smaller and you'll see why I can't do that.

Comment: @trusktr: What do you want the behavior to be upon resizing your window smaller, then?

Comment: When the window is smaller, all the asides appear in their correct inline positions, but I want it so when the browser window is bigger, all the images appear on the right as if it were a sidebar on the right.

Comment: The width issue?  Try applying fixed width. Or you could put all the left-side elements into a separate left-floated div, and all the aside elements into a separate right-floated div. Does that work for you?

Comment: Well I want the website to shrink on purpose... so people with mobile phones can have a nice experience too. It is supposed to do that. Check this out: try resizing your browser so it is like the width of an Android phone or iPhone. The images will be inline in the content right where they should be. But when you are on the full desktop version, I'd like for those `<aside>`s to be all on the right, and all atarting from the top.

Comment: Just read your new edits, so guess not. Not sure you can do that just with CSS. How about you make a CSS add-on just for phones?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. XD

Comment: Well, make a new CSS rule for the phones only: #main aside {float: none;}

Comment: Right, I get that part. But when float:right is active, I still want to make the images go to the top of the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<aside>` tags above the `<p>` tags in the `#main` div.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, but try resizing your browser smaller and you'll see why I can't do that. I edited my question.

Comment: So you want the images to be at the top of the sidebar in a normal browser but when it's been resized to a smaller width, you want them to be where they currently are?

Comment: Exactly! That's exactly what I want. I thought maybe there's some way to tell the `<aside>` elements to go to the top with CSS.

Comment: There's always a way to do it with Javascript, but I'm not so sure about CSS in this case.

Comment: I think if you applied CSS to move it up, it would be the same way when the screen minimized.

Comment: Hmmm... and what CSS might that be? hehe

Comment: Something like, `aside{margin-top:-200px}`

Comment: Hmmmm.... I could use Javascript to detect that initial margin so that'd definitely be an easy solution!

Answer (score 0):

Float the `<p>`, `inline-block` the `<aside>`'s... see http://jsfiddle.net/LuckyKind/KH8wA/

```
p, ul, ol, dl, blockquote {
    max-width: 40em; /* Optimal width for long-form text */
    float:left;
}

aside {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 18em;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt luckybird, but now the same thing happens to the paragraphs. Now I need to make the paragraphs all go up. Notice the space between the paragraaphs now: http://cis.scc.losrios.edu/~cisw320b_stu022/sccwa-snapshot2/

Comment: I see what you're talking about now triscuit. Your best bet is going to be something where you set the aside's up in a sidebar to begin with... and then when the screen get's to mobile size, collapsing it underneath the content... ultimately, it's sidebar content as you mentioned... so it's not as important as the main content.